# Printing a corresponding value of a column in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have a table with 3 parameters "Date", "Time"  and "Value". I want to add a new column to this table which has values corresponding to "Time" after every **10 minutes**.

[image]

I though of creating a new column with Seconds for ease.

Now I want a new column suppose "x" which would have the first vlaue and the values which correspond to the "Time" only after 10 minutes. What can we do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can first remove `dates` and `hours` by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html), add `10 Min`, then convert to `miliseconds` and divide `1000`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['08:01:29:12','08:03:29:12','08:05:29:12'],
                   'Date':['1/2/2016','1/2/2016','1/2/2016']})  
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%H:%M:%S:%f')
```

---

```
df['new'] = df.Time.sub(df.Time.values.astype('<M8[h]') + 
            pd.offsets.Minute(10)).astype('timedelta64[ms]') / 1000

print (df)

        Date                    Time     new
0 2016-01-02 1900-01-01 08:01:29.120  689.12
1 2016-01-02 1900-01-01 08:03:29.120  809.12
2 2016-01-02 1900-01-01 08:05:29.120  929.12
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df.Time.sub(df.Time.values.astype('<M8[h]') + 
            pd.to_timedelta('00:10:00')).astype('timedelta64[ms]') / 1000

print (df)
        Date                    Time     new
0 2016-01-02 1900-01-01 08:01:29.120  689.12
1 2016-01-02 1900-01-01 08:03:29.120  809.12
2 2016-01-02 1900-01-01 08:05:29.120  929.12
```